# Why does my print always starts from page bottom instead of starting from top?

Tags: css

My print page always starts from page bottom wasting about 60% of paper instead of printing from the page top. It starts from top if i use fixed position but all pages are clumped into one page instead of scaling into necessary number of pages.

[image]

```
@media print
{
    body, header, footer,aside, nav, form, iframe, .menu, .hero, .adslot
    {
        visibility: hidden;
    }

.   page-break  
    {
        page-break-before : always;

        page-break-inside : avoid;
    }

    #print
    {
        visibility: visible;
    }    

    table 
    {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        line-height: 2em;
    }

    table td 
    {
        text-align: center;
    }    
}

@page
{
   size: A5;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
body, header, footer,aside, nav, form, iframe, .menu, .hero, .adslot
{
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

to

```
body, header, footer,aside, nav, form, iframe, .menu, .hero, .adslot
{
    display: none;
}
```

When you use `visibility: hidden;` space is still allocated for those elements on the page, they're just not seen. `display: none;` will not show the elements at all on the page, although they'll still exist in the dom.